# Passing class via delegate : property not updated

Tags: swift, class, delegates, parameter-passing

don't understand why I didn't get my class property updated (imageData property).

simple example, 2 view controllers embed in navigation controller (important for me):

first one : ViewController with an imageView and a button to the second view controller (via segue)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, choosePicVCDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true    
  }

  func goodPic(vc: choosePicViewController) {

    if let data = vc.imageData {
      let image = UIImage(data: data)
      self.imageView.image = image
    }
    vc.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! choosePicViewController
    vc.delegate = self
  }

}
```

second one : choosePicViewController with an imagePicker to choose the image to display in the first ViewController. 2 buttons: one to choose the image, the other to go back to the first view controller with the delegate..

```
protocol choosePicVCDelegate {
  func goodPic(vc: choosePicViewController)
}

class choosePicViewController: UIViewController {

  var delegate: choosePicVCDelegate?
  let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
  var imageData: NSData?

  @IBAction func back(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.goodPic(self)
  }

  @IBAction func coverPick(sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
      imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
      imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
      self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

}

extension choosePicViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }

  func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

always got nil from imageData property, don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your extension, i didn't understand why use extension in this case, whatever. Try do it.

You need set delegate from `imagePicker.delegate = self`, because with this you can listener the `UIImagePickerController` delegate. I believe with this you resolve.

```
protocol choosePicVCDelegate {
    func goodPic(vc: choosePicViewController)
}

class choosePicViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var delegate: choosePicVCDelegate?
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var imageData: NSData?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        imagePicker.delegate = nil;
    }

    @IBAction func back(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.goodPic(self)
    }

    @IBAction func coverPick(sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    //Delegates from UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
            self.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)
            delegate?.goodPic(self)
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope help you!

Comment: you were right, just miss the  imagePicker.delegate = self in viewDidLoad() thanks !